# C-c C-v to not switch focus to Evince?

Tags: auctex

Whenever I run `C-c C-v` to view the corresponding part of the PDF of the point, the focus switches to the PDF viewer (evince in my case). Is it possible to make the focus stay in Emacs?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by adding

```
(setq TeX-view-evince-keep-focus t)
```

to `~/.emacs`.

A new feature in https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/commit/?id=6dcf0e1083791902563afaac9add4211bd91514a .